# Configuration management : if upgrade fail then rollback

Tags: configuration, upgrade, rollback

I'm trying to develop fully stand-alone server that would be able to upgrade themselves without any human intervention. To be more acute, here are the requirements :
   - Every nights the server checks for updates on a specified server :
   - When a upgrade is available, it downloads a new configuration file or something
   - Then the server proceeds its upgrade but if anything goes wrong (internet connection is lost or something is badly downloaded) the server rolls back to its previous configuration.

In fact we don't really care if the server isn't up to date but we want to be sure that its still running (even in a old version). I've looked for configuration management system and found fancy tools like Puppet. But, for instance, if puppet can't download a new debian package, the update will failed and there's a risk that the server can't fullfil it's task.

So i was wondering, do I have to check if every packages are correctly downloaded before launching the upgrade or is there any fancy tools that can do it for me and rollback if needed ?

One point is very important, once a server is deploy, we can't have any access to it. That's why it's better to have it running in an older version than to have it not running.

I hope that you'll understand my issue, sorry for my english

Julian